# WinJS save changes in the current page, then navigate to another page?

Tags: navigation, store, winjs

I am trying to save 4 different variable values before I navigate to another page. I've heard it was possible to store those values in the sessionState. I'm just not quite sure how to do it.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986966.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Navigation-sample-cf242faa

G